# pgfplots: swap x and y axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm looking to swap the x and y axes of a pgfplot (it was generated by matlab2tikz if that makes any difference).

I've tried the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140600/swap-x-and-y-axis-on-data-generated-plot) but it just leaves an empty plot

Example of what I want to swap:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=2.513032in,
height=2.580423in,
at={(1.010315in,0.641161in)},
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
xmin=0,
xmax=0.5,
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=0.5,
ymax=3
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   1.26800290431887\\
0.001   1.25779733180178\\
0.002   1.24778918646184\\
0.003   1.23797342537063\\
0.004   1.22834518617747\\
0.005   1.21889978357635\\
0.006   1.20963269924053\\
0.007   1.20053957382121\\
0.008   1.19161619967179\\
0.009   1.18285851678661\\
0.01    1.17426260069605\\
0.011   1.16582466119502\\
0.012   1.15754103679009\\
0.013   1.1494081841277\\
0.014   1.1414226790295\\
0.015   1.1335812069814\\
0.016   1.12588056104606\\
0.017   1.1183176366821\\
0.018   1.11088942722449\\
0.019   1.10359301993483\\
0.02    1.09642559220732\\
0.021   1.08938440957598\\
0.022   1.08246681883459\\
0.023   1.07567024804938\\
0.024   1.0689922017859\\
0.025   1.06243025846441\\
0.026   1.05598206865352\\
0.027   1.04964535006298\\
0.028   1.04341788534\\
0.029   1.03729752380501\\
0.03    1.0312821721302\\
0.031   1.02536979800197\\
0.032   1.01955842532153\\
0.033   1.01384613233683\\
0.034   1.00823104983074\\
0.035   1.00271135978001\\
0.036   0.997285294271756\\
0.037   0.991951129636677\\
0.038   0.986707190310741\\
0.039   0.981551845311729\\
0.04    0.976483503497566\\
0.041   0.971500617052248\\
0.042   0.966601678730505\\
0.043   0.961785217056348\\
0.044   0.957049799328648\\
0.045   0.952394028680916\\
0.046   0.947816542815464\\
0.047   0.943316013313831\\
0.048   0.938891145348908\\
0.049   0.934540672531718\\
0.05    0.930263362532376\\
0.051   0.926058010957684\\
0.052   0.921923441626197\\
0.053   0.91785850836601\\
0.054   0.913862087845381\\
0.055   0.909933087952989\\
0.056   0.906070437597304\\
0.057   0.902273092603433\\
0.058   0.8985400323419\\
0.059   0.894870258444431\\
0.06    0.891262795413782\\
0.061   0.88771668964968\\
0.062   0.884231009366011\\
0.063   0.880804842050305\\
0.064   0.8774372964526\\
0.065   0.87412749846869\\
0.066   0.870874596105447\\
0.067   0.867677753899353\\
0.068   0.864536152577956\\
0.069   0.861448993348423\\
0.07    0.8584154917185\\
0.071   0.855434881619604\\
0.072   0.852506410603373\\
0.073   0.849629344858323\\
0.074   0.846802961890524\\
0.075   0.844026557013429\\
0.076   0.841299437750494\\
0.077   0.838620926826746\\
0.078   0.835990360000383\\
0.079   0.833407085895066\\
0.08    0.830870467125539\\
0.081   0.828379877329155\\
0.082   0.825934703402202\\
0.083   0.823534343952432\\
0.084   0.821178208007939\\
0.085   0.818865718788038\\
0.086   0.816596307782295\\
0.087   0.814369417471005\\
0.088   0.812184502271299\\
0.089   0.810041025553044\\
0.09    0.807938460555489\\
0.091   0.805876292412277\\
0.092   0.803854012670429\\
0.093   0.801871124160652\\
0.094   0.799927138602753\\
0.095   0.798021575195676\\
0.096   0.796153963409339\\
0.097   0.794323840824239\\
0.098   0.792530751737693\\
0.099   0.790774250186985\\
0.1 0.789053897356521\\
0.101   0.787369262938834\\
0.102   0.785719922147752\\
0.103   0.784105459829927\\
0.104   0.78252546555359\\
0.105   0.780979538990763\\
0.106   0.779467284952025\\
0.107   0.777988313090232\\
0.108   0.776542242968735\\
0.109   0.775128697504599\\
0.11    0.773747309181222\\
0.111   0.772397714344386\\
0.112   0.771079554222036\\
0.113   0.76979247954076\\
0.114   0.768536143950469\\
0.115   0.767310206694322\\
0.116   0.766114333779833\\
0.117   0.764948195636674\\
0.118   0.763811468910293\\
0.119   0.762703835542992\\
0.12    0.761624980063783\\
0.121   0.760574595237155\\
0.122   0.759552376413031\\
0.123   0.758558024902386\\
0.124   0.757591245716929\\
0.125   0.756651748316941\\
0.126   0.755739249345856\\
0.127   0.754853465478815\\
0.128   0.75399412027849\\
0.129   0.753160941859679\\
0.13    0.752353660803368\\
0.131   0.751572013296088\\
0.132   0.750815737542518\\
0.133   0.750084578780112\\
0.134   0.749378282329543\\
0.135   0.748696600180605\\
0.136   0.748039285422627\\
0.137   0.74740609758307\\
0.138   0.746796798222745\\
0.139   0.746211150920981\\
0.14    0.745648925400651\\
0.141   0.745109892343379\\
0.142   0.744593827832812\\
0.143   0.744100508500642\\
0.144   0.743629717341814\\
0.145   0.743181238443412\\
0.146   0.742754858299114\\
0.147   0.742350367908857\\
0.148   0.741967560156571\\
0.149   0.741606230890862\\
0.15    0.74126618069137\\
0.151   0.740947209472781\\
0.152   0.740649122478381\\
0.153   0.740371726299852\\
0.154   0.740114831341597\\
0.155   0.739878249021342\\
0.156   0.739661794851652\\
0.157   0.739465285600094\\
0.158   0.739288540867879\\
0.159   0.739131382628075\\
0.16    0.738993636123444\\
0.161   0.738875127764296\\
0.162   0.738775685121622\\
0.163   0.738695141743068\\
0.164   0.738633329285223\\
0.165   0.738590083313346\\
0.166   0.73856524315805\\
0.167   0.738558646222521\\
0.168   0.738570135828112\\
0.169   0.738599555922481\\
0.17    0.738646752030326\\
0.171   0.738711570375501\\
0.172   0.738793863166705\\
0.173   0.738893480143888\\
0.174   0.73901027463922\\
0.175   0.739144103635621\\
0.176   0.739294821392924\\
0.177   0.739462289190801\\
0.178   0.73964636600189\\
0.179   0.739846914584803\\
0.18    0.740063799045994\\
0.181   0.740296883832101\\
0.182   0.740546036632421\\
0.183   0.740811126797158\\
0.184   0.741092024470191\\
0.185   0.741388600584837\\
0.186   0.741700729508264\\
0.187   0.742028285296498\\
0.188   0.742371145002031\\
0.189   0.742729186409229\\
0.19    0.743102288030507\\
0.191   0.743490331601041\\
0.192   0.743893197951627\\
0.193   0.744310771389502\\
0.194   0.744742936896367\\
0.195   0.74518958012493\\
0.196   0.745650587395471\\
0.197   0.746125849847206\\
0.198   0.746615255384033\\
0.199   0.747118695780155\\
0.2 0.747636063427738\\
0.201   0.748167251401808\\
0.202   0.748712156667585\\
0.203   0.749270672710692\\
0.204   0.749842697642368\\
0.205   0.750428130210536\\
0.206   0.751026869729018\\
0.207   0.751638816074753\\
0.208   0.752263871202349\\
0.209   0.752901937644691\\
0.21    0.753552920090837\\
0.211   0.754216722304689\\
0.212   0.754893250085291\\
0.213   0.755582411720758\\
0.214   0.756284113325517\\
0.215   0.756998264880241\\
0.216   0.757724775326118\\
0.217   0.758463556053835\\
0.218   0.759214518927599\\
0.219   0.759977576282928\\
0.22    0.760752640924427\\
0.221   0.761539629641316\\
0.222   0.762338455418947\\
0.223   0.763149035379017\\
0.224   0.76397128707585\\
0.225   0.764805128494416\\
0.226   0.765650478048356\\
0.227   0.766507254578011\\
0.228   0.767375381114489\\
0.229   0.768254776528835\\
0.23    0.769145363716699\\
0.231   0.770047065966843\\
0.232   0.770959806959378\\
0.233   0.77188351076401\\
0.234   0.772818101907535\\
0.235   0.773763508758184\\
0.236   0.77471965554214\\
0.237   0.775686470461108\\
0.238   0.776663882142927\\
0.239   0.777651819570779\\
0.24    0.778650212081635\\
0.241   0.779658989364708\\
0.242   0.780678082808333\\
0.243   0.781707424161417\\
0.244   0.782746946023908\\
0.245   0.783796580655454\\
0.246   0.784856261986446\\
0.247   0.785925924268221\\
0.248   0.787005502071695\\
0.249   0.788094931553442\\
0.25    0.789194148677396\\
0.251   0.790303089832011\\
0.252   0.791421692001461\\
0.253   0.792549894190553\\
0.254   0.793687634387338\\
0.255   0.794834851488727\\
0.256   0.795991486056859\\
0.257   0.797157477254722\\
0.258   0.798332765506317\\
0.259   0.79951729403427\\
0.26    0.80071100305187\\
0.261   0.801913835242691\\
0.262   0.803125733990571\\
0.263   0.80434664294046\\
0.264   0.805576505997367\\
0.265   0.806815267325305\\
0.266   0.808062871346243\\
0.267   0.809319265642113\\
0.268   0.810584393638197\\
0.269   0.811858204252646\\
0.27    0.813140643128091\\
0.271   0.814431657794111\\
0.272   0.815731196327275\\
0.273   0.817039207037419\\
0.274   0.818355638466721\\
0.275   0.819680441660282\\
0.276   0.821013564177664\\
0.277   0.822354957707182\\
0.278   0.823704571504609\\
0.279   0.825062358217863\\
0.28    0.826428268704305\\
0.281   0.827802254629193\\
0.282   0.829184268364655\\
0.283   0.830574262720181\\
0.284   0.831972191981732\\
0.285   0.833378008077215\\
0.286   0.834791665712842\\
0.287   0.83621311919845\\
0.288   0.837642323819678\\
0.289   0.839079233814024\\
0.29    0.840523805116661\\
0.291   0.84197599384979\\
0.292   0.843435756321954\\
0.293   0.844903049027332\\
0.294   0.846377828645058\\
0.295   0.84786005289665\\
0.296   0.849349680194679\\
0.297   0.850846667238016\\
0.298   0.852350973599531\\
0.299   0.853862557991438\\
0.3 0.855381378932929\\
0.301   0.856907396184734\\
0.302   0.85844056967349\\
0.303   0.859980859491146\\
0.304   0.861528225894357\\
0.305   0.863082629315082\\
0.306   0.864644032864348\\
0.307   0.866212395336514\\
0.308   0.867787680487001\\
0.309   0.869369848563867\\
0.31    0.870958863630886\\
0.311   0.872554687696041\\
0.312   0.87415728343181\\
0.313   0.875766614240684\\
0.314   0.877382643671623\\
0.315   0.879005335419538\\
0.316   0.880634654007424\\
0.317   0.882270564313428\\
0.318   0.883913029443722\\
0.319   0.885562016220347\\
0.32    0.887217487860298\\
0.321   0.888879412457336\\
0.322   0.890547753781463\\
0.323   0.892222478284541\\
0.324   0.893903552548466\\
0.325   0.895590943284718\\
0.326   0.897284617333924\\
0.327   0.898984541665422\\
0.328   0.900690683376815\\
0.329   0.90240300985282\\
0.33    0.904121490787914\\
0.331   0.905846091677219\\
0.332   0.907576783254608\\
0.333   0.909313531966752\\
0.334   0.911056308264317\\
0.335   0.912805080843845\\
0.336   0.914559818542484\\
0.337   0.916320491087473\\
0.338   0.918087068319744\\
0.339   0.919859520193551\\
0.34    0.921637816776094\\
0.341   0.923421928296656\\
0.342   0.925211827083151\\
0.343   0.927007481940287\\
0.344   0.928808864738457\\
0.345   0.930615946973538\\
0.346   0.932428700087626\\
0.347   0.934247094999161\\
0.348   0.936071105171007\\
0.349   0.937900701969444\\
0.35    0.93973585752512\\
0.351   0.941576544516642\\
0.352   0.943422735721892\\
0.353   0.945274404017716\\
0.354   0.947131522379604\\
0.355   0.948994065157357\\
0.356   0.9508620051533\\
0.357   0.95273531518503\\
0.358   0.954613971251212\\
0.359   0.956497945085563\\
0.36    0.958387213399925\\
0.361   0.960281748553623\\
0.362   0.962181525804819\\
0.363   0.964086521197288\\
0.364   0.965996708493545\\
0.365   0.967912063037797\\
0.366   0.969832560260796\\
0.367   0.971758175679569\\
0.368   0.973688884897155\\
0.369   0.975624663983207\\
0.37    0.977565489757342\\
0.371   0.97951133707859\\
0.372   0.98146218241813\\
0.373   0.983418003824361\\
0.374   0.985378775836325\\
0.375   0.987344477449245\\
0.376   0.989315084256784\\
0.377   0.991290573305352\\
0.378   0.99327092320465\\
0.379   0.995256110827874\\
0.38    0.997246113549118\\
0.381   0.999240909275948\\
0.382   1.00124047599078\\
0.383   1.00324479175064\\
0.384   1.00525383468698\\
0.385   1.00726758375348\\
0.386   1.00928601757924\\
0.387   1.01130911381602\\
0.388   1.01333685181392\\
0.389   1.01536921124992\\
0.39    1.0174061698096\\
0.391   1.01944770828992\\
0.392   1.02149380509776\\
0.393   1.02354443935067\\
0.394   1.02559959231632\\
0.395   1.02765924275205\\
0.396   1.02972337047754\\
0.397   1.03179195569946\\
0.398   1.03386497868908\\
0.399   1.03594241978208\\
0.4 1.03802425937839\\
0.401   1.04011047794196\\
0.402   1.04220105600063\\
0.403   1.0442959756844\\
0.404   1.04639521674241\\
0.405   1.04849875962652\\
0.406   1.05060658772098\\
0.407   1.05271867992487\\
0.408   1.05483501979642\\
0.409   1.05695558677952\\
0.41    1.05908036478294\\
0.411   1.06120933420041\\
0.412   1.06334247685544\\
0.413   1.06547977502183\\
0.414   1.06762121152844\\
0.415   1.06976676818962\\
0.416   1.07191642716708\\
0.417   1.07407017095771\\
0.418   1.07622798211339\\
0.419   1.07838984408215\\
0.42    1.08055573914836\\
0.421   1.08272564990627\\
0.422   1.08489955912487\\
0.423   1.08707745119642\\
0.424   1.08925930852695\\
0.425   1.09144511398334\\
0.426   1.09363485249523\\
0.427   1.09582850595743\\
0.428   1.09802605913317\\
0.429   1.10022749562307\\
0.43    1.10243279844713\\
0.431   1.10464195229431\\
0.432   1.10685494175402\\
0.433   1.10907175006495\\
0.434   1.11129236160417\\
0.435   1.11351676079587\\
0.436   1.11574493211124\\
0.437   1.11797686006838\\
0.438   1.12021252923214\\
0.439   1.122451924214\\
0.44    1.12469502987437\\
0.441   1.12694183218168\\
0.442   1.12919231473459\\
0.443   1.13144646232865\\
0.444   1.13370426202398\\
0.445   1.1359656971902\\
0.446   1.13823075419512\\
0.447   1.14049941790179\\
0.448   1.14277167459571\\
0.449   1.14504750843729\\
0.45    1.14732690726268\\
0.451   1.14960985530218\\
0.452   1.15189633838807\\
0.453   1.15418634266904\\
0.454   1.15647985492092\\
0.455   1.15877686077752\\
0.456   1.16107734621734\\
0.457   1.1633812975498\\
0.458   1.16568870112396\\
0.459   1.16799954332843\\
0.46    1.17031381097122\\
0.461   1.17263149094981\\
0.462   1.17495256925171\\
0.463   1.17727703242159\\
0.464   1.17960486738449\\
0.465   1.18193606242753\\
0.466   1.18427060249285\\
0.467   1.1866084759813\\
0.468   1.18894966943071\\
0.469   1.19129417025138\\
0.47    1.19364196532088\\
0.471   1.19599304298825\\
0.472   1.19834738913151\\
0.473   1.20070499252148\\
0.474   1.20306584059556\\
0.475   1.20542992026335\\
0.476   1.20779721939159\\
0.477   1.21016772588065\\
0.478   1.21254142766438\\
0.479   1.21491831295249\\
0.48    1.21729836926561\\
0.481   1.21968158462318\\
0.482   1.22206794759157\\
0.483   1.22445744602372\\
0.484   1.22685006805287\\
0.485   1.22924580184517\\
0.486   1.23164463559963\\
0.487   1.23404655825906\\
0.488   1.23645155880099\\
0.489   1.23885962436156\\
0.49    1.24127074463532\\
0.491   1.24368490817316\\
0.492   1.24610210300374\\
0.493   1.24852231913181\\
0.494   1.25094554429492\\
0.495   1.25337176787286\\
0.496   1.25580097938275\\
0.497   1.25823316661099\\
0.498   1.26066831962409\\
0.499   1.26310642791967\\
0.5 1.26554747980681\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: You probably get an empty plot because you used the linked solution without updating the `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax` values hard-coded by `matlab2tikz`. Is that the case? Does it work if you also swap the min/max values?

Comment: Hit the nail on the head -- silly me for not spotting that! Thanks.

Comment: I am voting to close, as your problem semingly has been solved by @Paul Gessler's comment.