# Draw flipped bar chart with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I make a graph like this one

[image]

from the data

```
String, Value
======
Some text, 1.9
Another text, 3.1
Yet another text, 0.9
```

So it is like a bar chart but with a line.

I guess it is something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    symbolic x coords={a small bar,a medium bar,a large bar},xtick=data]
    \addplot[ybar,fill=blue] coordinates {
        (a small bar,42)
        (a medium bar,50)
        (a large bar,80)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

but I don't know how to flip it so text labels are on the left instead of below, and I also want to 'separate' the rows either with background colors on every second row or by the horizontal lines as I drew in my example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to swap x- and y-axis, by using `xbar` instead of `ybar` and `symbolic y coordinates` instead of `symbolic x coordinates`. Moreover, you have to swap the x- and y-components in the data pairs, either explicitly in the code or implicitly when processing the pairs.

**Explicit swapping of components**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  [symbolic y coords={a small bar,a medium bar,a large bar},
   ytick=data,
   xbar,
   y=0.7cm,
   enlarge y limits={abs=0.5cm},
  ]
  \addplot[fill=blue] coordinates
    {(42,a small bar)
     (50,a medium bar)
     (80,a large bar)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you remove `xbar` and `fill=blue`, then you get an ordinary plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  [symbolic y coords={Some text,Another text,Yet another text},
   ytick=data,
   y=0.7cm,
   enlarge y limits={abs=0.5cm},
  ]
  \addplot coordinates
    {(1.9,Some text)
     (3.1,Another text)
     (0.9,Yet another text)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Implicit swapping of components** (inspired by [swap x and y axis on data generated plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140605/110998))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  [symbolic y coords={a small bar,a medium bar,a large bar},
   ytick=data,
   xbar,
   y=0.7cm,
   enlarge y limits={abs=0.5cm},
  ]
  \addplot[fill=blue] plot table
    [ignore chars={(,)}, col sep=comma, x index=1, y index=0, header=false]
    {(a small bar,42)
     (a medium bar,50)
     (a large bar,80)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For the output of the code see above. By removing again `xbar` and `fill=blue`, you get an ordinary plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  [symbolic y coords={Some text,Another text,Yet another text},
   ytick=data,
   y=0.7cm,
   enlarge y limits={abs=0.5cm},
  ]
  \addplot plot table
    [ignore chars={(,)}, col sep=comma, x index=1, y index=0, header=false]
    {(Some text,1.9)
     (Another text,3.1)
     (Yet another text,0.9)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can make the label texts left-aligned and look like a table with every second row having a different background color?

Comment: @Jamgreen No, not without checking the docs. Just ask a new question with the code that you plan to use.